# Any alternative for the queue() function - SweetAlert2 v11.4.8

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2, metronic

```
swal.queue is not a function TypeError: swal.queue is not a function
```

I would like to know the ways for the alternative of `queue()` function because it's now removed on the newer version. I tried adding the javascript library via the  tag but was not possible because it was being bundled with other js libraries in `scripts.bundle.js`. I'm using Metronic theme and I don't want to update the bundled scripts with the outdated version of sweetalert which still has the `queue()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's no support for queuing alerts as it can be handled by Js Intervals/Promises.
for example:

```
swal( {title: 'Modal 1', timer: 2000}).then(function(){ swal({title: 'Modal 2', timer: 2000}) })
```

or:

```
await swal({ title: 'Modal 1', timer: 2000 });
```

have a look [here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/809).